# Postgis distance filter does not work as expected

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5

I have a issue with simple PostGIS query.

Here is a query:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  location,
  ST_Distance_Sphere(location, ST_MakePoint(21.012228699999998, 52.2296756)) AS distance
FROM pins
WHERE
  ST_Distance_Sphere(location, ST_MakePoint(21.012228699999998, 52.2296756)) > 6008000.1836031
ORDER BY distance ASC, id ASC 
LIMIT 11;
```

And here is a result:

```
id  |                      location                      |     distance     
-----+----------------------------------------------------+------------------
  58 | 0101000020E6100000E253B4CB61C1E13FB7ED0CC45974EF3F |  6008000.1836031
 162 | 0101000020E6100000DE133C027D95E03F3C15FD84A6BAEF3F | 6008157.46639754
 186 | 0101000020E6100000D339D99403BFE33F541C1E242AD5EE3F |  6008257.4084038
  55 | 0101000020E6100000B8042A79A500E63F775E82BA1908EE3F | 6008878.66960698
  98 | 0101000020E6100000CD48F884CD1BED3FAD51BA15F017EC3F | 6008923.81556693
  56 | 0101000020E6100000EECE76EEFE68E63F1681C811377DED3F | 6010325.52640522
 195 | 0101000020E6100000EB87B04B4DC0E33F0AEAE22BECADED3F | 6012118.48976013
 100 | 0101000020E6100000603039EEF27FD83FE70E98797AAEEF3F | 6012318.05377066
 108 | 0101000020E610000045BA52BB3EA0E23F4B96A28081D5ED3F | 6012631.63019378
 117 | 0101000020E61000003ABE6BC7FAD9D43F4D1CF4D130EEEF3F |  6013175.7742802
  91 | 0101000020E610000093B62A082965ED3F911CF0DA8FBFEA3F | 6013178.70288832
```

For some reason row with id = 58 is returned and its distance is `6008000.1836031` despite I've used where filter `ST_Distance_Sphere(location, ST_MakePoint(21.012228699999998, 52.2296756)) > 6008000.1836031`

I guess Postgis calculates distance with greater precision?
How I can avoid this situation?

Comment: Probably a side effect of using an approximate data type like `float` or `double` (not sure what `st_distance_sphere()` returns): http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by converting distance to `numeric` and rounding:

```
round(ST_Distance_Sphere(location, ST_MakePoint(21.012228699999998, 52.2296756))::numeric, 2)
```

I've found it here http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Distance_Sphere.html, under "Examples".